# Docker gradle access denied

Tags: java, spring, docker, dockerfile

i tried to build docker image using docker-compose but i got this error

```
/bin/sh: 1: ./gradle: Permission denied
```

my Dockerfile is

```
FROM gradle:6.5.0-jdk11 AS TEMP_BUILD_IMAGE
ENV APP_HOME=/usr/app/
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY build.gradle.kts settings.gradle.kts $APP_HOME

COPY gradle $APP_HOME/gradle
COPY --chown=gradle:gradle . /home/gradle/src
USER root
RUN chown -R gradle /home/gradle/src

RUN ./gradle build || return 0
COPY . .
RUN ./gradle clean build

FROM openjdk:11-jdk
ENV ARTIFACT_NAME=app.jar
ENV APP_HOME=/usr/app/

WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY --from=TEMP_BUILD_IMAGE $APP_HOME/build/libs/$ARTIFACT_NAME .

ENTRYPOINT exec java -jar ${ARTIFACT_NAME}
```

and this is what i got in the shell

```
D:\Docker>docker-compose up -d
Building config-server
Step 1/17 : FROM gradle:6.5.0-jdk11 AS TEMP_BUILD_IMAGE
 ---> a001e5b2850a
Step 2/17 : ENV APP_HOME=/usr/app/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 07cf3a267c37
Step 3/17 : WORKDIR $APP_HOME
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 87be3841245e
Step 4/17 : COPY build.gradle.kts settings.gradle.kts $APP_HOME
 ---> Using cache
 ---> eff11fa2348e
Step 5/17 : COPY gradle $APP_HOME/gradle
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 10fca093f82e
Step 6/17 : COPY --chown=gradle:gradle . /home/gradle/src
 ---> b1f888f97818
Step 7/17 : USER root
 ---> Running in bde4f2d435fe
Removing intermediate container bde4f2d435fe
 ---> e8fba435db0c
Step 8/17 : RUN chown -R gradle /home/gradle/src
 ---> Running in d88ea2196f38
Removing intermediate container d88ea2196f38
 ---> b5b4727dd51f
Step 9/17 : RUN ./gradle build || return 0
 ---> Running in d218205301d9
/bin/sh: 1: ./gradle: Permission denied
Removing intermediate container d218205301d9
 ---> da37b296879b
Step 10/17 : COPY . .
 ---> e6cfac4a75a3
Step 11/17 : RUN ./gradle clean build
 ---> Running in 34480bf73106
/bin/sh: 1: ./gradle: Permission denied
ERROR: Service 'config-server' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c ./gradle clean build' returned a non-zero code: 126
```

how can i solve this error please?

Comment: Pretty sure you mean to have `RUN gradle build` on line 11 of the Dockerfile. And you should not be trying to copy a `gradle` binary into a container that already has one.

Comment: thank you @wmorrell for your reply.. so what should i change to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a base image which has gradle by itself. So, you don't need to copy gradle explicitly. Just remove `./` from gradle `RUN`.

```
RUN gradle build || return 0
COPY . .
RUN gradle clean build
```

Output

```
Step 9/17 : RUN gradle build || return 0
 ---> Running in fd470c45e443

Welcome to Gradle 6.5!

Here are the highlights of this release:
 - Experimental file-system watching
 - Improved version ordering
 - New samples

For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/release-notes.html

Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

> Task :buildEnvironment

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

classpath
No dependencies

A web-based, searchable dependency report is available by adding the --scan option.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 25s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
Removing intermediate container fd470c45e443
 ---> dd4056a53129
Step 10/17 : COPY . .
 ---> 3a46c7e9d9bb
Step 11/17 : RUN gradle clean build
 ---> Running in c3341e91aef0

Welcome to Gradle 6.5!
```